# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the GetObject operation

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore

Even though passing the the correct Access key, Id and token, I am getting an error while running a below code. Anything missing in this code?

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(
    region_name='us-east-1',
    aws_secret_access_key='XXXX',
    aws_access_key_id='YYYY',
    aws_session_token= 'ZZZZ')

s3_client = session.client('s3')
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket = 'dev-bucket-test', 
                                Key='abc.xlsx')
data = response['Body'].read()
print(data)
```

```
Error:

    botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the GetObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-key-error/

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a better approach.

There is a **credentials** file in **.aws** directory try to put your credentials there under **[default]** profile and it will help you to make all calls without writing credentials in code.